# PR2 base controller algorithm

Tags: ros, base-controller, pr2-controllers

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi!

I am using the PR2 base controller algorithm for another robotic platform. So far, the algorithm works perfectly for me, but I would like to know whether there is any documentation about how it works, how it calculates wheel angles and velocities and whether it can be used for an arbitrary number of wheels.

Thanks in advance!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/9703/pr2-base-controller-algorithm/) by [gazkune](https://answers.ros.org/users/165/gazkune/) on ROS Answers with karma: 219 on 2011-04-11

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi Gazkune,

This is very interesting! Could you please send me a pointer to some movies of your platform. I can put together a brief technical report for you on how everything works on the PR2 but it won't be until a couple of weeks at the earliest if that's ok with you.

---

Originally posted by [Sachin Chitta](https://answers.ros.org/users/39/sachin-chitta/) with karma: 1304 on 2011-04-13

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gazkune](https://answers.ros.org/users/165/gazkune/) on 2011-06-18**:
Hi Sachin. Do you have any new about the brief technical report you mentioned? I would be very happy to hear about you. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi Gazkune,

I don't found any documentation about the intern algorithms running in the base controller. But you can still take a look at
{ROS_STACKS}/pr2_controllers/pr2_mechanism_controller/src/pr2_base_controller.cpp
{ROS_STACKS}/pr2_controllers/pr2_mechanism_controller/src/pr2_base_controller2.cpp

In these files you will see two functions:
computeDesiredCasterSteer.
computeDesiredWheelSpeeds.
I think they describe what you are seeking.

Moreover, as far as I can see, this code is not dependent on the number of wheels.

Hope this helps,

Guido

---

Originally posted by [Guido](https://answers.ros.org/users/279/guido/) with karma: 514 on 2011-04-11

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2